# i have a line from html 'copy element' and i am trying to make a regex to strip out the irrelevant and keep the list

Tags: python, python-re

html_str:

```
'<canvas id="ratings_histogram" data-json="[10,4,4,5,8,8,9,10,10,7,9,6,6,7,3,7,7,2,4,3,10,4,8,4,4,4,8,10,4,7,10,7,5,8,1,10,6,4,9,7,1,1,7,10,3,9,5,1,4,7,2,1,6,5,2,5,7,10,10,5,5,4,1,7,10,6,7,4,4,4,9,1,7,10,1,6,10,1,3,2,8,10,3,10,9,2,6,1,4,1,8,3,5,10,5,5,4,3,7,3,4,1,1,6,10,3,1,2,6,7,4,7,6,1,7,3,5,4,6,4,7,9,10,3,7,5,8,5,6,6,1,5,4,10,3,1,2,1,6,10,8,8,6,6,10,7,7,7,7,7,4,10,1,6,6,4,4,7,7,5,1,4,10,4,1,10,2,3,2,7,10,4,1,8,8,6,7,2,10,8,8,3,1,7,10,10,8,5,1,1,5,10,6,6,4,10,1,8,4,8,3,10,10,3,10,5,1,10,4,7,9,6,3,6,6,6,9,9,8,7,1,6,6,5,4,3,7,10,1,4,5,10,7,1,10,1,8,4,9,10,5,1,7,9,4,8,7,10,9,10,9,1,7,6,1,7,1,1,7,5,9,2,10,3,3,4,1,10,9,2,9,10,6,1,3,5,1,6,1,7,5,8,10,4,10,7,3,10,3,5,10,10,6,10,1,4,9,7,7,6,6,1,4,4,7,5,5,10,1,10,7,4,5,7,7,10,1,3,10,6,8,5,10,10,9,5,5,7,2,9,1,8,10,10,5,6,3,4,1,5,7,4,1,1,1,8,8,8,8,10,6,10,10,6,9,4,8,4,6,7,10,9,8,10,7,7,1,1,5,7,6,8,7,10,6,7,7,6,10,9,10,7,8,8,7,1,10,9,5,7,7,9,8,4,10,4,7,1,7,10,1,7,9,7,5,10,8,8,10,8,10,8,8,10,1,10,7,5,3,1,10,7,1,9,10,7,5,8,7,6,5,10,5,5,10,6,6,4,9,7,8,1,2,2,7,4,1,8,7,7,1,10,3,1,6,10,1,8,7,8,6,5,6,8,6,3,10,5,6,2,7,8,9,10,10,2,1,5,10,1,10,4,1,7,7,10,8,1,4,3,3,9,9,10,9,10,6,4,5,10,10,8,3,8,8,10,7,5,7,9,1,5,10,2,7,5,9,10,1,4,7,8,2,10,10,8,4,10,10,8,5,4,4,10,1,8,6,6,5,7,6,7,8,10,10,6,4,7,5,4,9,6,10,10,1,6,10,1,1,8,10,4,7,4,7,7,6,7,7,9,7,4,10,4,7,6,8,4,5,9,6,8,8,6,5,8,5,6,10,9,3,7,10,9,8,7,7,6,7,5,5,8,8,10,7,8,1,2,7,7,10,10,1,6,7,10,9,8,9,1,1,10,8,2,9,1,4,4,5,6,2,1,4,10,6,1,3,2,10,2,8,7,10,8,5,6,10,7,7,1,6,7,8,6,8,6,1,1,5,8,8,1,4,5,7,10,5,6,6,7,7,6,1,7,7,5,7,7,4,4,8,6,2,9,6,7,10,2,3,8,10,6,2,9,3,4,10,2,7,8,7,6,7,4,7,7,9,5,7,7,6,7,7,7,10,9,10,4,10,8,10,5,6,4,8,7,7,5,6,8,10,8,6,9,7,9,8,7,5,8,2,6,10,10,10,8,2,7,3,8,1,6,5,7,10,7,5,5,8,2,9,6,7,9,6,8,6,7,6,5,8,6,10,1,5,7,7,8,7,7,7,10,10,7,10,3,8,1,8,10,5,7,8,7,8,8,4,1,10,7,7,10,9,5,7,10,10,10,9,10,1,10,8,4,4,10,9,5,6,9,7,7,10,5,10,10,7,6,6,7,6,4,7,8,7,7,3,7,10,2,6,8,10,7,8,1,10,7,9,7,10,6,6,5,9,7,7,3,7,10,5,7,9,10,5,5,7,8,8,8,8,1,9,8,10,6,7,8,4,8,7,6,8,8,8,7,7,10,8,6,10,10,9,3,7,5,8,9,7,8,7,3,7,9,7,6,7,10,6,10,8,1,7,8,7,8,9,8,8,1,10,9,10,7,8,3,3,10,9,9,6,1,4,8,6,4,8,5,9,10,8,10,8,6,6,6,6,9,9,10,8,8,8,7,3,7,6,6,1,10,7,6,4,10,4,3,3,5,6,9,10,7,10,5,6,1,10,10,6,1,9,5,4,7,6,4,7,10,5,6,10,1,7,7,8,4,6,10,9,7,9,9,4,10,7,4,6,9,5,4,10,9,2,7,5,7,5,7,5,8,7,8,10,4,5,8,1,6,8,5,10,5,7,6,9,10,5,8,10,9,10,8,1,7,8,7,6,10,8,10,4,8,6,10,7,6,10,6,9,6,1,7,1,8,10,10,9,1,10,10,6,4,9,10,4,8,10,8,10,8,3,5,4,1,1,6,7,8,7,2,10,8,8,9,8,6,7,5,1,8,3,10,10,10,3,10,8,6,9,4,8,5,8,6,9,10,7,6,10,7,10,10,5,10,5,6,7,10,7,6,9,6,6,10,5,8,8,4,7,7,7,6,9,8,2,6,3,7,4,4,6,8,8,10,7,9,9,5,10,8,8,8,9,8,9,10,10,1,9,2,10,5,2,7,8,7,7,7,9,8,8,8,7,8,10,4,5,7,6,8,7,7,4,8,8,10,1,10,8,8,6,10,7,2,2,1,10,10,7,7,7,7,3,10,10,7,7,10,6,1,8,10,6,10,10,8,8,4,10,9,1,9,9,6,7,7,7,6,1,1,10,7,2,10,9,5,8,3,8,7,5,8,10,10,6,4,10,9,8,4,5,10,10,8,8,8,8,7,9,1,2,6,5,3,10,10,9,7,7,10,6,5,6,6,6,5,7,7,10,7,7,1,10,6,10,9,10,3,8,1,7,5,7,7,10,10,1,4,10,8,1,9,10,7,8,6,7,10,6,6,4,1,7,6,8,9,10,7,8,8,7,9,10,10,10,8,9,6,4,9,7,10,7,3,8,8,7,5,7,5,10,7,9,7,9,7,10,8,6,10,8,10,4,1,1,7,10,1,5,7,8,7,7,7,5,8,7,7,8,6,10,7,5,6,3,5,8,2,8,7,8,7,7,9,7,10,3,7,10,7,9,5,10,8,7,10,7,8,10,8,4,7,9,7,10,10,9,10,3,9,9,7,4,6,7,5,10,1,5,7,10,9,7,10,3,7,7,3,9,7,7,10,6,8,7,8,6,7,8,1,3,1,10,10,8,7,3,8,6,9,4,8,8,8,10,9,10,10,7,8,10,8,10,10,9,10,4,2,7,7,10,7,8,7,7,9,8,9,9,9,8,9,7,4,10,10,7,10,7,8,8,10,5,7,7,10,10,8,7,7,7,7,9,8,7,5,7,4,5,7,7,8,6,1,9,7,8,7,9,10,9,1,10,6,7,10,7,9,10,9,8,7,10,8,7,10,9,8,7,9,9,10,8,7,8,5,10,8,5,9,5]" height="191" width="384" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; height: 213px; width: 427px;"></canvas>'
```

I know it's a mess, but don't know how to edit html well enough to avoid breaking things.

what I want is to make a 'small' thing that edits for only the json-data content between the brackets  just a list.

so far I have:

```
val_list = re.match(r'[^[](\d+\,)+\w', html_str)
```

*not including open bracket; 1 or more digits followed by a comma, any number of that whole selection, and the last digit.*

which stores NoneType to val_list.

the goal is to then convert to a list, but if there's 'nothing' to convert to a list I am stuck.

after the answer provided below, the finished code:

```
def json_extract(html_str):
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import json
    import numpy
    
    canvas = ET.fromstring(html_str)
    if 'data-json' in canvas.attrib:
        val_list = json.loads(canvas.attrib['data-json'])    

    tot = sum(val_list) + 45    
    bayes_average = tot/(len(val_list)+10)    
    average = numpy.mean(val_list)
    
    return print('bayes average: {} \naverage {}'.format(bayes_average,average))


#new cell
html_str = '<canvas id="ratings_histogram" data-json="[10,4,4,5,8,8,9,10,10,7,9,6,6,7,3,7,7,2,4,3,10,4,8,4,4,4,8,10,4,7,10,7,5,8,1,10,6,4,9,7,1,1,7,10,3,9,5,1,4,7,2,1,6,5,2,5,7,10,10,5,5,4,1,7,10,6,7,4,4,4,9,1,7,10,1,6,10,1,3,2,8,10,3,10,9,2,6,1,4,1,8,3,5,10,5,5,4,3,7,3,4,1,1,6,10,3,1,2,6,7,4,7,6,1,7,3,5,4,6,4,7,9,10,3,7,5,8,5,6,6,1,5,4,10,3,1,2,1,6,10,8,8,6,6,10,7,7,7,7,7,4,10,1,6,6,4,4,7,7,5,1,4,10,4,1,10,2,3,2,7,10,4,1,8,8,6,7,2,10,8,8,3,1,7,10,10,8,5,1,1,5,10,6,6,4,10,1,8,4,8,3,10,10,3,10,5,1,10,4,7,9,6,3,6,6,6,9,9,8,7,1,6,6,5,4,3,7,10,1,4,5,10,7,1,10,1,8,4,9,10,5,1,7,9,4,8,7,10,9,10,9,1,7,6,1,7,1,1,7,5,9,2,10,3,3,4,1,10,9,2,9,10,6,1,3,5,1,6,1,7,5,8,10,4,10,7,3,10,3,5,10,10,6,10,1,4,9,7,7,6,6,1,4,4,7,5,5,10,1,10,7,4,5,7,7,10,1,3,10,6,8,5,10,10,9,5,5,7,2,9,1,8,10,10,5,6,3,4,1,5,7,4,1,1,1,8,8,8,8,10,6,10,10,6,9,4,8,4,6,7,10,9,8,10,7,7,1,1,5,7,6,8,7,10,6,7,7,6,10,9,10,7,8,8,7,1,10,9,5,7,7,9,8,4,10,4,7,1,7,10,1,7,9,7,5,10,8,8,10,8,10,8,8,10,1,10,7,5,3,1,10,7,1,9,10,7,5,8,7,6,5,10,5,5,10,6,6,4,9,7,8,1,2,2,7,4,1,8,7,7,1,10,3,1,6,10,1,8,7,8,6,5,6,8,6,3,10,5,6,2,7,8,9,10,10,2,1,5,10,1,10,4,1,7,7,10,8,1,4,3,3,9,9,10,9,10,6,4,5,10,10,8,3,8,8,10,7,5,7,9,1,5,10,2,7,5,9,10,1,4,7,8,2,10,10,8,4,10,10,8,5,4,4,10,1,8,6,6,5,7,6,7,8,10,10,6,4,7,5,4,9,6,10,10,1,6,10,1,1,8,10,4,7,4,7,7,6,7,7,9,7,4,10,4,7,6,8,4,5,9,6,8,8,6,5,8,5,6,10,9,3,7,10,9,8,7,7,6,7,5,5,8,8,10,7,8,1,2,7,7,10,10,1,6,7,10,9,8,9,1,1,10,8,2,9,1,4,4,5,6,2,1,4,10,6,1,3,2,10,2,8,7,10,8,5,6,10,7,7,1,6,7,8,6,8,6,1,1,5,8,8,1,4,5,7,10,5,6,6,7,7,6,1,7,7,5,7,7,4,4,8,6,2,9,6,7,10,2,3,8,10,6,2,9,3,4,10,2,7,8,7,6,7,4,7,7,9,5,7,7,6,7,7,7,10,9,10,4,10,8,10,5,6,4,8,7,7,5,6,8,10,8,6,9,7,9,8,7,5,8,2,6,10,10,10,8,2,7,3,8,1,6,5,7,10,7,5,5,8,2,9,6,7,9,6,8,6,7,6,5,8,6,10,1,5,7,7,8,7,7,7,10,10,7,10,3,8,1,8,10,5,7,8,7,8,8,4,1,10,7,7,10,9,5,7,10,10,10,9,10,1,10,8,4,4,10,9,5,6,9,7,7,10,5,10,10,7,6,6,7,6,4,7,8,7,7,3,7,10,2,6,8,10,7,8,1,10,7,9,7,10,6,6,5,9,7,7,3,7,10,5,7,9,10,5,5,7,8,8,8,8,1,9,8,10,6,7,8,4,8,7,6,8,8,8,7,7,10,8,6,10,10,9,3,7,5,8,9,7,8,7,3,7,9,7,6,7,10,6,10,8,1,7,8,7,8,9,8,8,1,10,9,10,7,8,3,3,10,9,9,6,1,4,8,6,4,8,5,9,10,8,10,8,6,6,6,6,9,9,10,8,8,8,7,3,7,6,6,1,10,7,6,4,10,4,3,3,5,6,9,10,7,10,5,6,1,10,10,6,1,9,5,4,7,6,4,7,10,5,6,10,1,7,7,8,4,6,10,9,7,9,9,4,10,7,4,6,9,5,4,10,9,2,7,5,7,5,7,5,8,7,8,10,4,5,8,1,6,8,5,10,5,7,6,9,10,5,8,10,9,10,8,1,7,8,7,6,10,8,10,4,8,6,10,7,6,10,6,9,6,1,7,1,8,10,10,9,1,10,10,6,4,9,10,4,8,10,8,10,8,3,5,4,1,1,6,7,8,7,2,10,8,8,9,8,6,7,5,1,8,3,10,10,10,3,10,8,6,9,4,8,5,8,6,9,10,7,6,10,7,10,10,5,10,5,6,7,10,7,6,9,6,6,10,5,8,8,4,7,7,7,6,9,8,2,6,3,7,4,4,6,8,8,10,7,9,9,5,10,8,8,8,9,8,9,10,10,1,9,2,10,5,2,7,8,7,7,7,9,8,8,8,7,8,10,4,5,7,6,8,7,7,4,8,8,10,1,10,8,8,6,10,7,2,2,1,10,10,7,7,7,7,3,10,10,7,7,10,6,1,8,10,6,10,10,8,8,4,10,9,1,9,9,6,7,7,7,6,1,1,10,7,2,10,9,5,8,3,8,7,5,8,10,10,6,4,10,9,8,4,5,10,10,8,8,8,8,7,9,1,2,6,5,3,10,10,9,7,7,10,6,5,6,6,6,5,7,7,10,7,7,1,10,6,10,9,10,3,8,1,7,5,7,7,10,10,1,4,10,8,1,9,10,7,8,6,7,10,6,6,4,1,7,6,8,9,10,7,8,8,7,9,10,10,10,8,9,6,4,9,7,10,7,3,8,8,7,5,7,5,10,7,9,7,9,7,10,8,6,10,8,10,4,1,1,7,10,1,5,7,8,7,7,7,5,8,7,7,8,6,10,7,5,6,3,5,8,2,8,7,8,7,7,9,7,10,3,7,10,7,9,5,10,8,7,10,7,8,10,8,4,7,9,7,10,10,9,10,3,9,9,7,4,6,7,5,10,1,5,7,10,9,7,10,3,7,7,3,9,7,7,10,6,8,7,8,6,7,8,1,3,1,10,10,8,7,3,8,6,9,4,8,8,8,10,9,10,10,7,8,10,8,10,10,9,10,4,2,7,7,10,7,8,7,7,9,8,9,9,9,8,9,7,4,10,10,7,10,7,8,8,10,5,7,7,10,10,8,7,7,7,7,9,8,7,5,7,4,5,7,7,8,6,1,9,7,8,7,9,10,9,1,10,6,7,10,7,9,10,9,8,7,10,8,7,10,9,8,7,9,9,10,8,7,8,5,10,8,5,9,5]" height="191" width="384" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; height: 213px; width: 427px;"></canvas>'

json_extract(html_str)
```

which, when you copy element from the certain website, you can find what the actual average, and bayes smoothed rating (add 1 to each category) would be.

After testing this on a few series on that website, their averages are close on some, and very much not close on others.

Note: the code will work with any list of numbers.

Comment: Regex is not the correct tool here.  I'd suggest an HTML parser to get the `data-json` attribute.

Comment: I somewhat agree, considering just copy pasting it into any text field lets me just copy paste out what i want, but it's more to sort of understand the basics of scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using an XML parser to get the data you need.  Then you can parse it as a JSON string.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

canvas = ET.fromstring(html_str)
if 'data-json' in canvas.attrib:
    data = json.loads(canvas.attrib['data-json'])
```

Comment: `AttributeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-60703037209f> in <module>
      4 if 'data-json' in canvas.attrib:
----> 5     data = json.loads(canvas.attrib['data-json'])
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'loads' `

Comment: @DerekWestlund Did you `import json` and `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`?  How are you running this code?  What version of Python?  It works fine for me with Python 3: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/NbsIwEITvfoqVLyESSRsCogTMjTfghhAyiYlN/RPZq5Y8feqUtGq9F3v1zXim61E6Ww6DMp3zCA@jc4FeiPyghREWj/EOPMDhSCbkHpwlRKLRl4AeGCS7mtuPyKiGUc9R2TZcpAroWs8NhYYjz0YVo6fidb6Ms5pv5qszBSlUK5HRYlNQ@FQNSkbLtyWFWvMQGK0l93gPmRe2ET4zzip0nkLAXgtGGxU6zfsKrtrV79vJroJFUXaP7dOwguViHV90v3t55twnhEyJWeyV37wzsUmMPftplRJ1g@Q3eALKwlOSc4zotSIQzwhEjxHJteNNmP2DTn8czum3oovf4Gxcp8PwBQ)

Comment: I found out i did a stupid, and made a method named json that i was using to do a different form of processing and didn't change the name to avoid conflicts. fixed now.